# Default values when creating a vector, C++

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // create a vector with 20 0s
    std::vector<int> arr(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<arr[i];
    return 0;
}
```

The above code creates a vector of 20 `0`'s and prints each one. If I change the constructor to `arr (20,1)` it creates a vector of 20 `1`s.

If I define a class:

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    Rectangle (int,int);
    int area () {return (width*height);}
};

Rectangle::Rectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = a;
  height = b;
}
```

And create a vector of `Rectangle`s instead of `int`s:

```
int main() {
    // create a vector with 20 integer elements
    std::vector<Rectangle> arr(20, Rectangle(2,2));
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<arr[i].area();
    return 0;
}
```

Twenty `4`s get printed. However, when I try:

`std::vector<Rectangle> arr(20);`

I get:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Rectangle; _Alloc = std::allocator<Rectangle>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Rectangle; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Rectangle>]':
prog.cpp:19:34: error: no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'
     std::vector<Rectangle> arr(20);
```

Do I need to define a constructor with no arguments to make this work? And in general, what happens when I don't provide a second argument to the `vector` constructor when I'm using non-primitive types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to define a constructor with no arguments to make this work?

Yes, see this link :
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector.

Here is the related constructor of `std::vector`.

> explicit vector( size_type count,
>                    const T& value = T(),
>                    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());

Without the second parameter, it is assumed to be `T()` via [**default parameter**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).
`T()` will become `Rectangle()` in your case.

When you call primitive with `std::vector`, it will act similar.
Roughly speaking, it will call *default-constructor*-syntax on the primitive e.g. `int()`, which yield 0.

[This ideone demo](http://ideone.com/30533b) shows that `int()==0`.

Comment: Note that constructor's signature changed since C++11, it doesn't have the default argument `T()` now.

Comment: @Adam  I agree with songyuanyao.  Adam, please also see the tiny green mark on the link "until C++11" and "since C++11".     The std::vector behavior can be different in different C++ version.

Comment: @songyuanyao Does that means it's not 0 in c++11?

Comment: @bigxiao The effect should be same.

Comment: @songyuanyao Why does the c++11 does not specify an default `allocator<T>` ,like the c++17 does? Does that mean it does not use an `allocator` in c++11?

Comment: @bigxiao It uses `allocator`, of course, it just gives a default value, you could still specify it.

Comment: Does the `explicit vector( size_type count )` in c++11 means that it needs an `allocator_t` with default constructor(When we declare `vector<value_t,allocator_t>` ),so that it does not need user to pass their allocator instance?

Answer (score 3):

A little tinkering with your prameterized constructor can solve the problem.
We have to just provide default parameter here.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle (int a=1, int b=1){
        width = a;
        height = b;
}
```

Now, if we call `std::vector arr(20);` it will execute properly and give your desired output.